# vue.js push array component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

1.vue.js problem component
i want insert a new message in new array with method on click event but 
not work for me because function is incomplete
where is the problem.
help me please.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <h1>{{message.title}}</h1>
  <h4>{{message.subtitle}}</h4>
  </p> {{message.body}}</p>
  <button v-on:click="newMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>

import {
  VueTabs,
  VTab
}
from "vue-nav-tabs";

import "vue-nav-tabs/themes/vue-tabs.css";

export default {
  components: {
    VueTabs,
    VTab
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "elenco",
      messages: [{
            id: 1,
            title: "titolo",
            subtitle: "sottotitolo",
            body: "argomento",
            author: "Amedeo",
            date: "17/07/2017",
            files: [{
              id: 1,
              title: "Allegatoriunione",
              openfile: "Allegato.pdf"
            }, ],
            methods: {
              newMessage: function() {
                this.message.title = this.message.title
                  .push("")
                  .split("")
                  .reverse()
                  .join("");
              }
```

Comment: What error you receive ?

Comment: button dont' work..

Comment: methods must be outside of `data`

Comment: give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Contains many syntax errors which probably fails silently.
Try this new updated code:

```
<script>
import { VueTabs, VTab } from 'vue-nav-tabs'
import 'vue-nav-tabs/themes/vue-tabs.css'

export default {
  components: { VueTabs, VTab },
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'elenco',
      messages: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'titolo',
          subtitle: 'sottotitolo',
          body: 'argomento',
          author: 'Amedeo',
          date: '17/07/2017',
          files: [
            {
              id: 1,
              title: 'Allegatoriunione',
              openfile: 'Allegato.pdf'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    newMessage() {
      this.message.title = this.message.title
        .push('')
        .split('')
        .reverse()
        .join('')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```